# Can't display putExtra in share at navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have code for share in navigation bar and i fetch package and text but my one putExtra line is not displayed.

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Hey Download this App Called\n App name");
                String sAux = " to Improve your Life's....... \nAt least One Time Try This\n";
                sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.kishorsinh.app \n\n";
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose one"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //e.toString();
            }
        }
```

i have use this code in app and share then it display only....

to Improve your Life's....... 
At least One Time Try This
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.kishorsinh.app

can anyone suggest me what is the problem? It's not reflecting putExtra field.

Comment: the question wants more description of what you want to do. Please update your question with more information. where do you want to display that `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_SUBJECT` ?

Comment: @Kishorsinh if you share it with email then only subject field works. Otherwise you will only get text fields `putExtra()`.

Comment: where are you trying to share? Whatsapp, Facebook, etc?

Comment: @RishabhSagar Yes

Answer (score 0):

I have changed whole program it may solve others problem it's worked perfect for me

```
   try {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    final String appPackageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
                    String strAppLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName;
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody = strAppLink;
                    String shareSub = "Hey Download this App Called\n Appname ........\nAt least One Time Try This\n";
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using"));
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {

                }
```

Comment: Share in Navigation bar all worked perfect but in Whatsapp it's only display link not text 

All other apps worked perfect telegram,mail etc....
 but in whatapp it's only display link not upper text..